# How to turn off safe_mode in php on Debian?

Tags: php, safe-mode, wkhtmltopdf

I know, it may sound ridiculous, but I can't turn off safe_mode. I'm using wkhtmltopdf (which is best html->pdf converter I've used, and yes, I tried html2ps, fpdf and lots of others). And it needs to be executed with exec() function. I've done

- *find / | grep php.ini*,

found all of php.ini's and changed safe_mode to Off. Then added

- *php_flag safe_mode Off*

to .htaccess and

- *php_admin_flag safe_mode Off*

to httpd.conf. And still I'm getting the following errors:

- `Warning (2): shell_exec()
  [function.shell-exec]: Cannot execute
  using backquotes in Safe Mode
  [APP/vendors/wkhtml/wkpdf.php, line
  79]`

---

**Update:**
Ok, I've found an answer. Since I had virtualhosts, each virtualhost had it's own httpd.conf inside of it's own directory, and it had "safe_mode off" inside of it.

Comment: Silly question: does `phpinfo()` inform you about more `.ini` files loaded?

Comment: well... as you can see, the problem was in https.confs, and not inside of .ini files. but thanks or advise.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found an answer. Since I had virtualhosts, each virtualhost had it's own httpd.conf inside of it's own directory, and it had "safe_mode off" inside of it.

Sorry for disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably forgot to restart your httpd.

Also, this question belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that then. :)

Answer (score 1):

maybe use ini_set() to disable safemode right before shell_exec() ? but propably ini_set is disabled in safemode as well...